# Statistical Test According to Independent Variables

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, continuous-data, variable

I wish to test a statistical significance between means of data groups.

The groups are determined by a continuous variable, however this continuous variable is applied to different test subjects (this is a biology lab). The lab, thus, has two independent variables - one is continuous and one is categorical. The dependent variable is continuous.

What kind of statistical test would I use? I understand that a two-way ANOVA test may only use categorical independent variables...

Here's my data:
[image]
Thank you for you help

0, 2.9, 5.8 and so on  represent my continuous independent variable

Comment: Can you show us some data? This looks like a job for linear regression.

Comment: The continuous variables represent grams of soluble fiber consumed. They are within a range of possible values. Do you think I could define them as interval categorical variables, and from there on do a two-way ANOVA test?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. So, did you recode the continuous independent variable into a categorical one? Is this why you state that there is one continuous and one categorical independent variable?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am defining the numerical independent variable as continuous because I measured them quantitatively.

Comment: Let me ask this way: what are those independent variables, one continuous and one categorical?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: If there is no specific reason, I would not recommend turning your continuous variable into a categorical one. You can test the association between two continuous variables using, for example, Pearson correlation, or some other suitable method.

Comment: "I wish to test a statistical significance between means of data groups.". Where are groups? Define the group based on which variable?